# Is it possible to modify this script to save the zip on the server instead of having the user download?

Tags: php

Okay so the script works perfectly if i want the user to select the files to download.  It prompts the user to save the zip file to there computer,
but i'd like to modify it to instead once they hit download, the script creates the zip file and saves it to the server for 24 hours and then it is deleted.

If the saving it to the server is too complicated, I can do a manual delete

The big issue is getting it to save the zip file to the server instead of prompting the user to download

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['files']))
{
$error = ""; //error holder
 if(isset($_POST['createzip']))
{
$post = $_POST; 
$file_folder = "files/"; // folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
// Checking ZIP extension is available
if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
{ 
// Checking files are selected
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
// Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
foreach($post['files'] as $file)
{ 
$zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // Adding files into zip
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
}

}
else
$error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>File Download</h1>
<form name="zips" action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /><label>Select All</label><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="file.zip"/><label>file</label><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="file2.zip"/><label>file2</label><br />
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="file3.zip"/><label>file3</label><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="createzip" value="Download All Seleted Files" >
</form>

<br /><br />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
      $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
      if ($('.chk').filter(':checked').length < 1){
            $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);}
});

$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
        if ($('.chk').filter(':checked').length < 1){
            $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);}
        }
});     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. **Edit:** and it's already happening.

Comment: do you want to explain in more detail?

Comment: What I mean is, your code is already saving the file in the server.

Comment: The script already saves it on the server in `$zip_name`. You may wish to [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) it to a different directory.  PHP cannot delete the old ones after 24 hours on its own, you would need to add a cron entry to find zip archives older than 24 hours and delete them.

Comment: where does it save it to the server or how do i change the path to save it to ?

Comment: `$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name` this part.

Comment: Why you prompt it to download using hedaer it already reside on server.you need to set a cron on server that runs once 24 hours and delete the file from server.

Comment: Okay so i found out how to keep it on the server THank you all for the help!

i added // to the unlink($zip_name);

Answer (score 0):

That library is already saving the zip file to disk:

```
$zip_name
```

and you are removing it with:

```
unlink($zip_name);
```

You could instead create a dedicated web accessible directory to hold the zip files, and save them into there. Then you could provide the user with an http link to the path of that file for download.

At that point you may want to create a cron job which purges zip files after X days so that you don't fill up the disk.